# OS X server, archive but no IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server

Tools - OS X Server: 4.0 and Xcode : 6.1

I have a problem with build server with IPA creation. I get succesfull xcarchive but no IPA. When I run the bot i get:

```
Bot Issue: warning. Build Service Error.
Issue: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 2..
Integration Number: 8.
Integration URL: https://pluto.local/xcode/bots/5BBB8A5/integrations
Description: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 2..
```

Firstable I cannot find anywhere what status code 2 mean. and Secondable when i go to archive and manually (from Orginizer) create IPA it works fine. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is the bot part of your team? The log may have more detailed information on the failure, but the most common problems are with signing.

Comment: Server has separate profiles for distribution and development. I can build using xcodebuild command with provisioning installed

Comment: Ah, but can you build using the same arguments to xcodebuild *as the server user*

Comment: It don't know what's happening under the hood in Bot. Can I check it somehow? With xcodebuild I am using default conf without pointing to different mobileprovision file

Comment: The output should be in the server or build log.

Comment: In Xcode, go to the specific integration, at the top of that view you should see "Logs". Scroll to the bottom for the build log.

Comment: @quellish Big thanks for a clue! Found a problem in post-archive script for crashlytics with interupt with a build. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some part of the archive step failed, but not in a way that completely blocks the build. Do you have any archive pre- or post- action steps?

For example, we have our CI system setup to push to beta using a script in the archive post-action step. I see this whenever this script fails.